# What is a readhead?

Tags: sensor

I found this term many times on this website : https://www.renishaw.com/en/rgh34-incremental-encoder-system-with-rgs40-linear-scale--6450

It seems to be something related to a sensor or a transducer, but I cannot find any definition of the term "readhead" online.

Comment: It's the read head. The head that reads. aka the sensor. The pickup. The business end. The thing that reads the strip.

Comment: Yup, mostly seen as two words.

Comment: Well, if you think about it for a minute...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The Renishaw read-head and scale.*

The system described has two parts:

- a scale
- a readhead or read-head

They have to be mounted so that they move relative to each other. I don't know the product but I imagine that either the scale or the read head can be mounted on the moving part.

> **What is RGS40 scale?**
>
> RGS40 is a tape scale manufactured from a thin flexible steel strip, featuring a 40 µm pitch, which is gold plated to give high reflectivity and corrosion resistance. ... The scale is supplied on a reel and can be cut to suit any axis length up to 50 m.
>
> **What is RGH34?**
>
> The RGH34 is a non-contact readhead that offers the performance and reliability of the established RG4 linear encoder system with the versatility of a miniaturised component system. ... In combination with the RGI interface, the RGH34 system is available with high resolution digital outputs up to 50 nm or with industry standard 1 Vpp analogue output.

This system will be somewhat similar to the common digital calipers (although the technology is different) in that a count is kept as the read-head moves along the scale. This count is converted to a digital position readout.

Answer (score 0):

Read head. Generally in the context of an encoder it's the active bit that "reads" the (passive) scale. Usually the scale moves and the read head is fixed, at least relative to the electronics that is connected to it.